# I have a file with 3 columns and 7 rows, I need to make 3 arrays out of each column in the file

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have been trying to figure this out for days and I feel that I am just stuck on something that is so easy from over thinking it. I need to read the file, (contents of what text file looks like are right below)... create 3 arrays out of each column.

My issue is when splitting the String under " " conditions into a String [] Array, takes the last row of my txt and puts that into the new String [] Array, not the entire contents of string that i made from file...

my txt file looks like this...

```
200 1000 800
450 845 1200
800 250 400
0 1500 1800
600 500 1000
700 1400 1700
675 400 900
```

my code so far after days of manipulation, deletion, starting over from scratch...all to come to this small piece. 
PLEASE HELP ME!!!

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class WeeklyCalorieCount {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

    File input = new File("Lab1File.txt");          //reads file and names it input to refer back later
            Scanner klg = new Scanner(input);               //creates scanner that reads the file named input

            String [] b = new String [7];               //creating breakfast, lunch and dinner Strings (To Split later)
            String [] l = new String [7];
            String [] d = new String [7];

            String fileLine = null;

            System.out.println("TEST 1: Contents of file are as follows: ");
            while (klg.hasNextInt()) {                  //Puts file contents into string
                fileLine = klg.nextLine();
                System.out.println(fileLine);
            }

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("TEST 2 BELOW");

            String strArr[] = fileLine.split(" ");      //temporary array to hold all numbers and split

            for(int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++){     //Trying to split String into individual elements and put into string array. 
                System.out.print(strArr[i] + " ");
            }

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("--------");
            for(int k = 0; k < strArr.length;k++) {
                b[k] = strArr[k];                       //Assigns contents into 3 arrays
                l[k] = strArr[k];
                d[k] = strArr[k];
                System.out.println(b[k]);
                System.out.println(l[k]);
                System.out.println(d[k]);
            }
```

OUTPUT:

```
TEST 1: Contents of file are as follows: 

200 1000 800
450 845 1200
800 250 400
0 1500 1800
600 500 1000
700 1400 1700
675 400 900

TEST 2 BELOW

675 400 900 
--------
675
675
400
400
900
900
```

Comment: Txt File reads as follows - but as in 3 columns and 7 rows
200 1000 800
450 845 1200
800 250 400
0 1500 1800
600 500 1000
700 1400 1700
675 400 900

Comment: After the `while` loop finishes which has `fileLine = klg.nextLine();`, `fileLine` will have only the last line. You are not concatenating the strings.

Comment: You should create a 3x7 matrix instead and read your values with `nextInt()`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a 3x7 matrix and two `for` loops, saving each `int` value separately:

```
File input = new File("Lab1File.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
int[][] matrix = new int[7][3];

for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        matrix[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
}
scanner.close();
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to avoid using a 2d array at first because the TA's in my Lab are super picky! But Ive been working all week and they still keep telling me .... try something else... try something else. ... i cant tell you. SO THANK YOU ... I will use this and create the methods using the matrix.

Comment: If you wish to avoid using a 2D Array but keep the same principle, create a class `DailyCalorieCount` which stores your 3 daily values. Then you just need to create a simple array of this type.

Answer (score 0):

After the `while` loop finishes which has `fileLine = klg.nextLine();`, `fileLine` will have only the last line. You are not concatenating the strings.

You are replacing `fileLine` with the line that you read every time. So you only have the last line after the loop.

You probably need to do:

```
fileLine = fileLine + " " + klg.nextLine();
```

instead of:

```
fileLine = klg.nextLine();
```

**Edit:**

You need to initialize `String fileLine = "";` with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are in :

- `fileLine = klg.nextLine();`  fileLine will have only one line
- `for(int k = 0; k < strArr.length;k++)`

Better you move the code in for loop to the `while (klg.hasNextInt())`:

```
int k = 0;
while (klg.hasNextInt()) {                  
    fileLine = klg.nextLine();
    System.out.println(fileLine);
    String strArr[] = fileLine.split(" ");
    b[k] = strArr[0];                       
    l[k] = strArr[1];
    d[k] = strArr[2];
    k++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it the way you initially planned as shown in the runnable below:

```
package weeklycaloriecount;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WeeklyCalorieCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare and initialize string variables to hold
        // the values from each column of each file line as
        // they are read in.
        String colA = "";
        String colB = "";
        String colC = "";

        try {
            File input = new File("Lab1File.txt");      
            Scanner klg = new Scanner(input);

            // Read each line of file until the end.
            while (klg.hasNextInt()) {
                // Place the line read into a String Array
                String[] fileLine = klg.nextLine().split(" ");
                // Take each element of the array and place them into
                // their respective column variable and delimit them
                // with a whitespace...
                colA+= fileLine[0] + " "; 
                colB+= fileLine[1] + " "; 
                colC+= fileLine[2] + " ";
            }
            klg.close();  // Close the scanner.
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // Trap the File Not Found Exception
            System.out.println("Whoops! File Not Found!");
        }

        // Display each String variable...
        System.out.println("The colA Variable:  " + colA);
        System.out.println("The colB Variable:  " + colB);
        System.out.println("The colC Variable:  " + colC);

        // You can at this point use each variable (colA, colB, and colC)
        // as your separated columns or you can place the contents of each
        // variable and place them into individual arrays as done below...
        String[] b = colA.trim().split(" ");
        String[] l = colB.trim().split(" ");
        String[] d = colC.trim().split(" ");

        // Display our Arrays (b[], l[], and d[])
        // Breakfast...
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("The b[] Array:   " + Arrays.toString(b));

        // Lunch...
        System.out.println("The l[] Array:   " + Arrays.toString(l));

        // Dinner...
        System.out.println("The d[] Array:   " + Arrays.toString(d));
    }

}
```